# Agora Dynamic Channels vs Static P2P Video

Tags: flutter, video, agora.io

I am working on a P2P Medical application for patient doctor engagement.
It appears I would need to create a token and APPID for each doctor. This would be labor intensive to manage. The application is written in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create an APP ID and token for every doctor. APP ID and token are unique fields that are unique to your application, so you have to just enter them once so as to authenticate your application with Agora.io servers. For doctors and patients, you will have to create channels, which is nothing but a unique string that is common between a doctor and a patient.

You can have a look at the official sample given over here: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Flutter-SDK/tree/master/example or this sample code given over here: https://github.com/Meherdeep/agora-group-calling